# How to check if device has infra-red in Android?

Tags: android, infrared

How do I know if device has Infra-red hardware in android pragmatically?

I want to have some things to be done based on this. I tried using something like below, but no luck.

```
this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature( .. various constants ..)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Use `ConsumerIrManager.hasIrEmitter()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/ConsumerIrManager.html#hasIrEmitter())

Answer (score 1):

Try Following Code

**Kotlin:**

```
val irManager: ConsumerIrManager = getSystemService(CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE) as ConsumerIrManager

        // Check whether IrEmitter is available on the device.
        if (irManager.hasIrEmitter()) {
            Log.i("IR_Testing", "found IR Emitter")       
        }else{
            Log.i("IR_Testing", "Cannot found IR Emitter on the device")
        }
```

**Java:**

```
private ConsumerIrManager irManager ;
irManager = (ConsumerIrManager) getSystemService(CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE);
 if (irManager.hasIrEmitter()) {
           Log.i("IR_Testing", "found IR Emitter");
        } else {
             Log.i("IR_Testing", "Cannot found IR Emitter on the device");
        }
```